# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Model.Room

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Trying to return entity selected fields but getting error

My Interface

```
public  interface IRoomRepository
{
    List<Room> All();

    Room Get(int id);

    Room Add(Room obj);


    void Delete(Room obj);

    void Update(Room obj);
}
```

My Repository and i implemented IRoomRepository

```
public List<Room> All()
    {
        using (HotelEntities db = new HotelEntities())
        {
            var result = from room in db.Rooms
                         select new
                         {
                             room.RoomNumber,
                             room.Id,
                             room.RoomType
                         };
            return result.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Getting the following error

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

EDIT

Room Model Class

```
namespace Model
 {
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Room
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string RoomNumber { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> RoomTypeId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> RoomStatusId { get; set; }

        public virtual RoomStatus RoomStatus { get; set; }
        public virtual RoomType RoomType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your All() method is returning a non room type its only returning 3 properties from room, not all of room

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create `Room` object explicitely.`new {}` creates anonymous object that can't be converted to `Room`. Assuming property names are the same, following should work

```
public List<Room> All()
{
    using (HotelEntities db = new HotelEntities())
    {
        var items = from room in db.Rooms
                     select new
                     {
                         room.RoomNumber,
                         room.Id,
                         room.RoomType
                     }.ToList();

        var result = items.Select(i=>
                       new Room  {
                         RoomNumber = i.RoomNumber,
                         Id  = i.Id,
                         RoomType  = i.RoomType
                     }).ToList();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: getting this : Cannot initialize type 'Room' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Comment: @rilly009 Can you post definition of `Room` class ?

Comment: Message=The entity or complex type 'hotelPlusModel.Room' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: In this case you can go for anonymous objects in the query and transform results later, see edited code

Comment: i am still getting errors on this. Is there no other method to exclude some fields from entity returns